# Maven Error: No plugin found for prefix 'archetype'

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm new to Java and trying to generate a maven project at the command line. This gives me an error:

*"No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\User.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]"*

After some research, I believe the error is because the system is trying to reach out to http://repo.maven..., but should instead reach out to https://repo.maven...
I made changes to settings.xml:

```
<repository>
<id>archetype</id>
<url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/</url>
</repository>
```

All of this is on my local system. Can someone please help with this. I'm using a windows 10 system.
Thanks

Comment: Please don't add error messages as image, but instead as text.

Comment: Change to https instead of http. Your are using probably an old Maven version (strongly recommend to upgrade)... the change you have posted of your settings.xml is simply wrong...